# Apple Mach-O Linker Errors when integrating Stripe and PaymentKit into Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, stripe-payments

I have successfully installed Stripe and Payment Kit into my Swift Xcode 6.4 project. However, whenever I build the project with code pertaining to Stripe I get the following Apple Mach-O Linker Errors.

Errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo6Stripe in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you posted at least some of those errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all the files are linked correctly, then try cleaning your build with Command-Shift-K.

Comment: Where would I check if files are linked correctly? CocoaPods said there it was successful in installing.

Comment: Have you cleaned the build?